# FCM notification click_action should redirect to open browser

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with fcm click operation, after receiving a notification, when I click on it, it should open browser which goes to "www.google.co.in", but when I click on notification it opens the default MainActivity.

Here is my onMessageReceived() :

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Message Data Payload:" + remoteMessage.getData());       
  Log.d(TAG, "Message notification body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.co.in"));
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                    .setContentText("FCM MessageBody")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Does anyone know what is the exact implementation or anything wrong in this code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of this topic, I suggest that you read this article
[firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Message Data Payload:" + remoteMessage.getData());       
  Log.i(TAG, "Message notification body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            switch (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()) {

                case "openUrlGoogle":
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.co.in"));
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                    break;

                case "openUrlOtherSite":
                    break;

                default:
                    Log.v("TAG", "error");
                    break;
            }

        }

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                    .setContentText("FCM MessageBody")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: I read the FCM documentation and searched, the above code works only when the app is in foreground, but if the app is in background / killed, fcm will send the data-messages to default activity and we have to retrieve using extras of Intent, I referred this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

Comment: So the onMessageReceived() won't get called when app is in background / killed.

Comment: even the code works only to set the custom notification when the app is in foreground and its not redirecting when I clicks on it and the notification is gone.

Comment: I am also facing the issue where onMessageReceived() is not getting called when the user taps on the notification when the app is killed. @Satish did you find a solution for this?

Comment: try this @SharathHuddar  https://dontkillmyapp.com/